# MySQL equality slower than greater-than

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm having a curious issue with my MySQL database. The following query runs in 0.003 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM `post` where `thread_id` > 12117484 and `index` > -1 limit 1;
```

If I change the second > to an =, the query doesn't complete (it runs for over a minute):

```
SELECT * FROM `post` where `thread_id` > 12117484 and `index` = 0 limit 1;
```

It's worth noting that the result from the first query has `index = 0`. I know it's bad form to name a column `index`...but it's the database I've been given. Here's the MySQL Explain for the second query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post  | range | post_thread_id_idx1 | post_thread_id_idx1 | 5       | NULL |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: examine query plans.....

Comment: Hi Mitch, I've added the EXPLAIN...it doesn't seem to be that informative, or maybe I'm reading it wrong?

Comment: you've added 1 EXPLAIN. Where's the other?